# How to use confirm in JavaScript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

```
   <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("lastasignment"); 
if(isset($_GET['act'])){
 $nid=$_GET['i']; ?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 if(confirm("you want to delete "+" <?php echo $nid ?>")){ 
<?php $i=$_GET['i']; 
mysql_query("delete from testings where id=$i");
 ?> ;
 }else {
alert("cancelled");
} 
</script>
```

The data in the table is deleted whether i click ok or cancel?

Comment: did it worked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a form you can do something like that:

```
<form onsubmit="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;">
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="delete" />
    <button name="i" value="1">Delete</button>
</form>
```

If you are using an anchor tag, you can use `onclick`:

```
<a href="YOUR_URL" onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;">Click Me</a>
```

And BTW, you should use GET for fetching things only, you should not use it for insert/update/delete. Use POST instead. The reason? for example, you don't want the user to access that link from his browser history, then you'll have a dupliacte entery / delete again / update again.

Comment: i am using an achor tag in php and passing the 'act' and 'i' in it.

Comment: Then it's pretty much the same, 1 sec I'll update my answer.

Comment: echo "<a href='?act=delet & na=$n & i=$i'>"."delete".'</a>

Comment: `echo "<a href='?act=delet & na=$n & i=$i' onclick=\"if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;\">delete</a>";`

Comment: it didn't work dear.

Comment: @DilawarAli It should. Take a look here: https://3v4l.org/IptpD#output

Comment: Finally it works dear, thanks a lot for your time and interest, i am very thankful to you,  i have been trying it for 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to alert the user whether to continue or not. Here is that code

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to do this thing into the database?')) {
    // operation to execute
} else {
    // operation on false
}
```

**call the function by onclick event in edit e.g(`onclick="showUser(this.value)"`)**

*AJAX:*

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {     
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to do this thing into the database?')) {
        // operation to execute
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
              document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","linktophp.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } else {
        alert("cancelled");
    }
}
</script>
```

*PHP FILE:*

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','****','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="DELETE FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

Comment: Soory, i pasted the other code, i am new here so i didnt know how to ask paste the required code.

Comment: it okay i understood by reading description & heading . i really got confused "what is with the PHP code" ,though

Comment: i want to delete a data from the database using php and javascript confirm. if the user clicks ok the data should be deleted and if he clicks cancel the data should not be deleted. But the error is the whether clicks or cancel the data is deleted.

Comment: place your php call in if condition. post your corect code

Comment: edit the question cant view clearly

Comment: can you provide the code in question .press edit located at bottom of question

Comment: it should work .i am wondering why it is not?

Comment: i did edit the question, but it is not working in the format you doing. plz help

Comment: do you prefer ajax

Comment: how can i do with ajax?

Comment: i ll show you now

Comment: ok, show me please

Comment: just copy & paste change change DB name table

Comment: i have edited the question, now i think you understand what i want to do.

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: i cant understand your code.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp   **refer this **

Comment: .when you click button it invokes function & passes value ,in that function  it confirms & execute ajax operation .ajax invokes php & it deletes record

Comment: sorry dear, i still cant understand, i am not good at ajax, can you give some solution by changing the above code. please

Comment: yes i got it i deletes the record because php code runs  before the script it will not go front and back by javascript. but it can be done with ajax that;s why i suggested ajax to you. it is also said  before 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567054/how-to-trigger-php-code-in-javascript-if-condition

Comment: but i am not good in ajax dear

Comment: there is no way did you read that answer he mentioned that also

Comment: yeah now i understand why it is not working, i have to do something else then, thanks for your help dear